# Recyclerview notifyItemRangeInserted called, but view not updating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having an annoying issue on RecyclerView, that it is getting its data properly, but the view won't redraw it self.
I am currently using androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01.

I had a chance to reproduce it recently, and these what I have found out so far.

1. RecyclerView is not null. (I am using kotlin extension)
2. RecyclerView has adapter attached.
3. RecyclerView has LayoutManager attached.
4. I dug into RecyclerView code deeper.

   - notifyItemRangeInserted() calls observables.notifyItemRangeInserted() internally.
   - in notifyItemRangeInserted(), it calls AdapterHelper.onItemRangeInserted, with returns whether there are any pendingUpdates. If there aren't any pendingUpdates, triggerUpdateProcessor is called and the view should update itself. In my case, **pendingUpdates weren't being cleared** with some reason, so with all the everlasting pendingUpdates, the view weren't updated
     [image]
     [image]

This might be a very vague question, because I can't provide specific code that is causing this issue (It is not crash-triggering).

I can't even find an exact way to reproduce it. The only thing I found out is, it 'often' happens when turning the app into foreground/background over and over till it happens. (SaveInstanceState might be a cause, but I didn't override it so it is doing its default feature)

Could anyone give any hint or at least some knowledge about this issue?
Or even any temporary expedient would be okay.. (maybe forcing the recyclerView to clear all the pendingIntents...)
Ready to provide additional information.

Thanks

Comment: a nice and simple library to avoid all that boilerplate stuff https://github.com/Link184/KidAdapter

Comment: @Link182 I don't think this is about the adapter and viewHolder logic... but thanks anyways for the convenient library. I was looking for these kind of library.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?